# Java why invocation of private method works

Tags: java, methods, private, invocation

I wonder why this

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{   
    class Print {
        public String name = "Timur";
        private void writeObject() {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
    class Write {
        public void callPrint(Print p) {
            p.writeObject();
        }
    }
    Print p = new Print();
    Write w = new Write();
    w.callPrint(p);
}
```

works in Java. Method `writeObject` is a private one, but still successfully called from other class object.
Question comes from definition of the [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). It says that if we want to overwrite serialisation process, we should declare `private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException` method of the serialisable object. Which means ObjectOutputStream could invoke it, nevertheless it's private.

Comment: no, it's not from another class. it's all within one single method, I'm pretty sure one method can be found in one class

Comment: A case for encapsulation principles within the scope of a method is a curious one

Comment: It's not a dublication. This question is about local class, not inner class

Comment: please read an update — last paragraph.

Comment: so for the last case with `ObjectOutputStream` reflection API is actually used.